# Add space above search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header, uisearchbar

I have a TableViewController embedded in a NavigationController. I have set a UISearchBar to the tableView's header.

```
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
```

However, I want some additional padding between the between the searchBar and navigationBar for some message. How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Embed your `searchbar` in a `UIView`, add padding with constraints, and set that UIView to the `tableHeaderView`.